# Will lack of image stabilization be a problem if I'm using a tripod?

Tags: lens, tripod, image-stabilization

I have been looking in to the Sigma 70-300mm F4-5.6 APO DG Macro for both its macro and telephoto capability, and noticed it does not have an optical image stabilizer.

I'm still new to photography but I know how optical image stabilizer affects the image in hand-held photography. My question is, will lack of  optical image stabilization have an effect when using a tripod?

Comment: Just in case you are interested, there's [handheld samples](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/39277/17441) shot with a non-APO version of this lens in my answer to another question.

Comment: Related for macro in specific: [How useful is image stabilization in a macro lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18930/how-useful-is-image-stabilization-in-a-macro-lens)

Answer (score 8):

If there is any impact, not having image stabilization will improve the lens performance on a tripod.  When using image stabilization, there has to be some room for parts of the lens to move freely.  Without image stabilization they can use more of a solid mount.

When using a tripod, you normally turn image stabilization off even if the lens has it, because it isn't needed and can actually be harmful since it causes lag when moving the camera.

Comment: ok thanks for the info i have a good tripod works well also did not know to turn off os when on a tripod like i said im still new to this but i am happy to get a new lens only reson im going with Sigma 70-300 F4-5.6 APO DG is it had some great reviews for starters and the price range for both marco and telephoto iv seen

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no additional benefit gained by having a form of image stabilization (IS, VC, VR, etc.) when using a lens with a tripod. There are exceptions to this, but the Sigma 70-300mm F4-5.6 APO DG Macro isn't one of them.

The Canon *Super Telephoto Series* lenses have some IS modes that are specifically designed to be used when the lens is mounted on a tripod, either for panning or for reducing the effect of mirror slap when shooting at very long focal lengths and certain shutter speeds.

Answer (score 1):

When using a tripod, you should turn off image stabilization anyway. That should give some ideas as to how much image stabilization (or absence of it) matters while using a tripod.

Comment: It depends on the specific lens and use.